# PHP ftp_chmod and Folder Permissions

Tags: php, upload, permissions, ftp

I am working on a PHP FTP Upload Script, which so far only works if the target folder on my FTP Server has permission settings 775 or 777.

I need sth. like the following code (which I know should only work on files not folders) to remotely change folder permissions:

```
ftp_chmod ($connection, '0775', './');
```

The upload script is not intended for my own FTP Servers, but to push Data from my Server to my Clients FTP Servers.

Is there any way of setting the correct permissions on my side, to take that off of my clients shoulders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way of setting the correct permissions on my side, to
>   take that off of my clients shoulders?

Only if their FTP server is misconfigured. If it has been properly configured then you should already have write access. If you don't, then you should never be able to grant it to yourself.

Comment: If I create a new folder on my Test FTP Server (with an FTP Client like Coda) it has 750. This however does not work. Just to get the right picture: In this scenario I ABSOLUTELY need Group Write Access, because my PHP is not executed on the Target Server? Is that right?

Comment: Correct, your PHP is not executed on the target server. However, the permissions requirements there should never be your concern -- they depend completely on how that server's admin has configured that one particular FTP daemon, and they'll vary between machines, and possibly even between userids on the same machine. You can't rely on any specific requirement to exist because, in all likelihood, both the user account you think you're logging into and the permissions that the FTP server is reporting are virtual.

Comment: I.e., your clients' FTP servers aren't necessarily going to require the same configuration as your own, so you can't assume that what fixes the problem on your server will fix the problem on theirs. (Unless you know for certain that your servers are identically configured, I suppose...)